# relative time from latest timestamp (subqueries)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

My Table in athena is a week behind today but it keeps catching up
so I want to create a query that gives me the all the sessions a week before the latest timestamp
I have something like that but it does not work

```
SELECT app_id, env, count(distinct session_id) as num_of_sessions, from_unixtime(timestamp/1000) as ts
FROM "sessions" 
where env='demo' and date(from_unixtime(timestamp/1000))>date_add('week', -1, (SELECT max(timestamp) FROM "sessions" where env='demo' limit 1))
group by app_id, env, from_unixtime(timestamp/1000)
order by from_unixtime(timestamp/1000)
```

and the error I get is

```
Error running query: SYNTAX_ERROR: line 3:58: Unexpected parameters (varchar(4), integer, bigint) for function date_add. Expected: date_add(varchar(x), bigint, date) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, time) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, time with time zone) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, timestamp) , date_add(varchar(x), bigint, timestamp with time zone)
```

I've never done a query inside a query so its probably the problem but i cant understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear.

As far as I see the column `timestamp` in the table sessions is type `bigint`. In fact it represents an unix timestamp and this is why you do `from_unixtime(timestamp/1000)`.

But in the `date_add` function that gives you an error, you simply do `max(timestamp)` that is still bigint type.

`date_add` func need the third parameter as `time` or date `type`, so you have to cast it as you do before, so:

```
date_add('week', -1, (
   SELECT from_unixtime(max(timestamp) / 1000) 
   FROM "sessions" 
   WHERE env='demo' limit 1)
)
```